# Throttled Requests metric against a Dynamodb table name is not shown when creating an Cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a AWS Dynamo DB table, for which I am trying to create Cloud Watch alarm for metric name Throttled Requests on Operation BatchGetItem. In the image (click on the link) you can see that Throttled request metric name is not displayed to choose it so as to create Cloud watch alarm. Can anyone help me to understand why it is not displayed ?

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h03iX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNtQz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Only metrics that have ever been recorded will be displayed. You can still create the alarm.

Comment: Hi Hunter, Yeah I created alarm but it shows as insufficient data as it's state. Is it fine to be so ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. With an alarm you have a choice on what to do with missing data. One choice is to "treat it as good", which is appropriate for this since no throttling data means happiness. More info at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html